# struct one byte larger than expected

Tags: struct, unions

I have a the following union

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t     bValue;
    uint16_t    uiValue;
    int16_t     iValue;
    uint32_t    ulValue;
    int32_t     lValue;
    struct { // Float messages
        float   fValue;
        uint8_t fPrecision; //Number of decimals when serializing
    };
    struct { //Presentation messages
        uint8_t version;        // Library version
        uint8_t sensorType;     // Sensor type hint for controller, see table above
    };
    char        data[MAX_PAYLOAD + 1];
} mysensor_payload_data;
```

and i want to use this union in the following typedef

```
typedef union {
    struct {

#endif
    uint8_t last;                // 8 bit - Id of last node this message passed
    uint8_t sender;              // 8 bit - Id of sender node (origin)
    uint8_t destination;         // 8 bit - Id of destination node
    uint8_t version_length;      // 2 bit - Protocol version
                                 // 1 bit - Signed flag
                                 // 5 bit - Length of payload
    uint8_t command_ack_payload; // 3 bit - Command type
                                 // 1 bit - Request an ack - Indicator that receiver should send an ack back.
                                 // 1 bit - Is ack messsage - Indicator that this is the actual ack message.
                                 // 3 bit - Payload data type
    uint8_t type;                // 8 bit - Type varies depending on command
    uint8_t sensor;              // 8 bit - Id of sensor that this message concerns.
    // Each message can transfer a payload. We add one extra byte for string
    // terminator \0 to be "printable" this is not transferred OTA
    // This union is used to simplify the construction of the binary data types transferred.
    mysensor_payload_data   payload_data;
};
uint8_t array[HEADER_SIZE + MAX_PAYLOAD + 1];
} /*__attribute__((packed))*/ MyMessage;
```

now when I run the following line of code

```
strncpy(message->payload_data.data, value, length);
```

the bytes get written at location 0x20000498 when "message" is at 0x2000490. I would expect the byte to be at 0x20000497 if i count correctly.

Why does it write at that location?

Comment: Short answer is, compiler chooses that location and it has the freedom to do so. Why do you care anyway?

Comment: Because the packet I send over the radio is payloaddata + header long and now I miss the last byte because there is one byte not used. Is there a way to force the compiler to do it as I want?